# Create rectangle instead of bubbles in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I used this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269 to create circles, but i would need to create rectangle instead of circle and all those rectangles needs to packed inside one bigger rectangle. please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can make rectangles instead of circles.

```
  node.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.r*2; })//width is the diameter
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.r*-1; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.r*-1; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.r*2; })//height is the diameter
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });
```

Now to create a rectangle which packs all of them

```
  //get all the data
  var data = d3.selectAll("g")[0].map(function(d) {
    return d3.select(d).data()[0]
  })
  //get the min x max x min y max y
  var xmin = d3.min(data, function(d){return d.x-d.r})
  var xmax = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.x+d.r})
  var ymin = d3.min(data, function(d){return d.y-d.r})
  var ymax = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.y+d.r})

  //make a rectangle to make it over other rectangles.
  svg.insert("rect" ,":first-child")
  .attr("x", xmin)
    .attr("y", ymin)
    .attr("height", ymax-ymin)
    .attr("width", xmax-xmin)
    .style("opacity", 0.3)
    .style("fill","blue");
```

working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/R36MK5IJbSNdPdFiWpOj?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. All these small rectangle need to be enclosed in a big rectangle and in your example all the small rectangle are overlapping and not equally spaced.

Comment: Sorry.. Pasted your above code for packing them in a big rectangle. It works fine.

Comment: for spacing between rectangles you can change the padding like this `var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
      .sort(null)
      .size([diameter, diameter])
      .padding(25.5);` working code here http://plnkr.co/edit/Ku250M0PeRutyQU4VJxn?p=preview

Comment: I created the below one, i made all the size same. It looks good now but looks like a hexagon. Instead of starting from top left corner (the small rectangle), seems they are created from center to outside. Any ways to remove all those spaces and space it uniformly?  Top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right has more white spacing  http://plnkr.co/edit/nQKzGqlpKSwW3JYpp2jA?p=preview